# How to use install_github() for .tar.gz files hosted on Github

Tags: r, github, package

A friend has created this file: *"their_tar_0.1.tar.gz"*. He told me that i can install it locally from this file alone, so i did via:

`install.packages("their_tar_0.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL)`

This worked absolutely fine with no issues. My issue is: I'd like to be able to host this on github publicly. I've saved this file within my github account in the regular format as: *"author/package"*, i.e. *"my_github_acc_name/their_tar_0.1"*. However, it seems that .tar.gz file is actually in the 'master' branch of this repo. Either way, when i try to install it via:

`install_github("my_github_acc_name/their_tar_0.1")`

or

`install_github("my_github_acc_name/their_tar_0.1.tar.gz")`

or

`install_github("my_github_acc_name/their_tar_0.1\their_tar_0.1.tar.gz")`

Which gives me the following error when i run it in RStudio:

`*Downloading GitHub repo my_github_acc_name/their_tar_0.1@master
Error: Failed to install 'their_tar_0.1' from GitHub:
  Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)*`

Any ideas what my problem is? I've looked at the package and various questions online, however none of the questions seem to relate specifically .tar.gz file types.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Dave

https://rawgit.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/package-development.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `help("install.packages")`:

> Usage
>
> install.packages(pkgs, lib, repos = getOption("repos"),
>   [... some content omitted ...]
>
> pkgs      character vector of the names of packages
>                whose current versions should be downloaded from the repositories.
>                If repos = NULL, a character vector of file paths,
>                on windows,
>   file paths of ‘.zip’ files containing binary builds of packages.
>                (http:// and file:// URLs are also accepted

So, you can just do

```
user    <- "my_github_acc_name"
repo    <- "their_tar_0.1"
branch  <- "master"
fname   <- "their_tar_0.1.tar.gz"
pkg_url <- paste("https://raw.github.com", user, repo, branch, fname, sep = "/")
install.packages(pkg_url, repos = NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks, duckmayr - I wish I had stumbled upon your answer before I wasted hours of my time on a similar problem